# Derivative squared equals one of parametrized curve?

Tags: geometry

In the book Do Carmo, Differential Geometry, they state in the text, without reasoning, that for a by arc length parametrized curve $\alpha(s)$, we have $\alpha'(s) \cdot \alpha'(s) = 1$, but I cannot seem to understand why. Could anyone explain why this is true? I have seen this result in other examples, proofs and exercises, so I would like to understand why that's true.

Comment: I don't believe it's appropriate to read the statement as "derivative squared equals one". Rather: *A curve $\alpha(s)$, parameterized by arc length, has a unit tangent vector $\alpha^\prime(s)$.* The expression $\alpha^\prime(s)\cdot\alpha^\prime(s)$ is computing the squared-length of the tangent vector using the dot product. The fact that this length is always $1$ is what makes arc-length parameterization the "natural" parameterization.

Comment: Ah, that puts things into perspectives. Also the rephrasing of that it means helped to understand it. Question is answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's appropriate to read the statement as "derivative squared equals one". Rather:

> A curve $\alpha(s)$, parameterized by arc length, has a unit tangent vector $\alpha^\prime(s)$.

The expression $\alpha^\prime(s)\cdot \alpha^\prime(s)$ is computing the squared-length of the tangent vector using the dot product. The fact that this length is always $1$ is what makes arc-length parameterization the "natural" parameterization.